# remove and disable featured image in posts

Tags: wordpress

I write a post in new post editor and then add media. I can see the images in the editor but when i publish them they aren't loading up and a frame with little square in the middle comes up. This is the link to one of my posts: http://getprogramcode.com/2013/03/c-program-for-bit-stuffing/ . For some people only link to the image comes up and it opens up with 404 error. See the line after OUTPUT: bit stuffing.

Also i want to remove the featured image from appearing in my posts. I have a option in my theme on a new post: "disable featured image" - but that doesnt work . Also if i dont put the image or i remove the featured image the empty image appears: see the home page: http://getprogramcode.com Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: ../wp-content/uploads/2013/03/C-program-for-bit-stuffing.png is wrong address for this image, i presume its  http://getprogramcode.com/2013/03/C-program-for-bit-stuffing.png have a look at the output for your theme and fix the url output, use get_site_url(); to build dynamic links to your images.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use relative paths on WordPress, only Absolute paths.

The problem is that you are using `../wp-content/...` as your URL's for image paths.

When adding images, you should have the option to give it a path, you should opt to link to the media file.

For the disable feature image, if you go into the `page.php` or `single.php` code, it should have a line of code in it for calling in the featured image.

It should look something like this:

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    the_post_thumbnail();
} 
?>
```

You just need to remove or comment out this code and it should stop showing up on the pages.